# Excel -- In VBA, how do I find all possible sums of values in a matrix using 1 value per row?

Tags: excel, matrix, vba

I've searched around a good bit for this answer, but nothing quite solves my issue. Here's what I'm doing...

I've got a worksheet that houses a matrix of [edit: 16rows x 9cols]. The cells of the matrix are positive and negative integers. Here's an example of a portion of the data:

[image]

I need to find all possible Summations with the condition that only one value can be chosen per row. In other words, I would take the first value in each row and add them up. Then, I would take the 2nd value of the first row and add it to all the other rows' first values...on and on until I am finding the summation of the last value of each row.

So to start, I would want to store the Sum of (-144, -16, 0, -96, -74, 0, 589, -61, -55, -18, -66, 0, -279, -24, -43, -406). The  next Sum to store would be (-5, -16, 0, -96, -74, 0, 589, -61, -55, -18, -66, 0, -279, -24, -43, -406).

I'm trying to think of a clever way to use a `For` loop with `GoTo` statements, but I'm open to any ideas. Perhaps a recursive function?

Comment: Where are you putting the results of the summations?  Or where do you want to put them?

Comment: I was thinking of just slapping them onto another sheet, but I'm open to ideas. I plan on doing a Remove Duplicates on the summations.

Comment: I just was testing some ideas out of my own and I was wondering if you knew the count of how many combinations there would be for a 16x56 matrix.  From reading your comments it sounds like the number of combinations would be (columns^rows).  For the example data you have, that would be 11^10 or 25937424601 which is already way to big for excel to handle let alone getting into the 16x56....is that count correct?

Comment: Thanks, @chancea. I'm able to remove most 0s and bring it down to a 16x9 matrix. I will update my post accordingly.

Comment: Your update reduces the number of combinations to a little over 8 * 10^9.  Still a lot but better than 9^16 = 2 * 10^15.  If you could generate all these combinations, where would you store the results?

Comment: Would you like a new algorithm that would handle the new data?  My first algorithm is no longer appropriate.

Comment: If you have one that is efficient (from a time perspective), then yes please!

Comment: I know how I would tackle your revised problem.  I don't know if all 8 thousand million combinations can be generated in a realistic time period.  I will experiment.  Do you really need all combinations?  If you could say: "I only need the positive ones" or something like that, the problem could become much more managable.

Comment: With Excel VBA, which is interpreted, I can generate 50,000,000 combinations in 13.25 minutes.  With VB.net which is compiled to machine code, the same number of combinations takes about 28 seconds.  This suggests that a VB.net program could complete the task in 70 minutes.  I can post the VB.net code or if you email me (see my profile for address) I can send the executable program.  By the way, I am outputting the sums to files with one sum per line.  I start a new file every 1,000,000 sums.  I have one 5Mb file but most are over 10Mb with 17Mb being the most common size.

Comment: I got the file sizes wrong.  I was appending rather than over writing They are closer to 6Mb each.

Comment: I have posted an explanation of my new solution and the VB.net code which told 51 minutes to create 8063 files with all but the last containing 1,000,000 sums.  I accidentally deleted the VBA code so cannot offer that.  If you have access to Visual Basic I have given you enough information to create the program.  Otherwise, email me and I will send you the executable program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to solve this type of problem with recursion but I find it easier without.

Consider a speedometer.  Each cycle adds one to the rightmost digit. If that digit overflows from nine to zero, you add one to the next digit to the left.  If that digit overflows, you add one to the digit to its left.  This continues until a digit does not overflow or the left-most digit overflows.  So the values you see on your speedometer are:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 2
: : : :
0 0 0 9
0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1
: : : :
0 0 1 9
0 0 2 0
: : : :
0 0 9 9
0 1 0 0
: : : :
9 9 9 9
```

If the digits of the speedometer are the entries in an integer array, a simple loop can cycle through these values.

For your problem:

- You need 16 entries in your array, one per row in your matrix.
- Each digit can take value between 0 and 55 rather than 0 to 9.

With this change, your speedometer cycles from:

```
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

to

```
 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55
```

If you number your columns from 0 to 55, each digit tells you which column to use for the corresponding row.

One of the values through which your speedometer cycles is:

```
 1 45  5 30  8 22  1  0 38 51 14 42 29 31 46  7
```

Which tells you to sum:

```
Column 1 of first row
Column 45 of second row
Column 5 of third row
Column 30 of fourth row
And so on
```

Another loop will extract and sum these values.

So the outer loops will cycle the speedometer from {0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0} to {55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55}.  For each value on the speedometer, the inner loop calculates and stores the sum.

**Section 2**

Little change is required to update the original code for the new requirement.

In the original, I had a “speedometer” that cycled from (0, 0, 0, …) to (55, 55, 55, …) with every “wheel” having values from 0 to 55.  I have now added an array which gives the maximum value for each “wheel.”  For example, the first “wheel” can take values 0 to 5 which correspond to the six values to be extracted from the matrix: -144   -5    0   12   16   20.

```
  5  2  4  8  2  1  1  3  1  5  7  1  8  3  4  5    New maximum values

  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0    Minimum values

 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55    Old maximum values
```

I typed the data from the image of your matrix into Sheet1 of a new workbook:

[image: Worksheet matrix]

My macro imported that matrix into a variant array.  There is an overhead for every access to a variable of type variant so I copied the data to a Long array.  To demonstrate the macro creates the array correctly, I output:

```
Row Lst ---0 ---1 ---2 ---3 ---4 ---5 ---6 ---7 ---8
  0   5 -144   -5    0   12   16   20
  1   2  -16    0   50
  2   4    0    5    8   11   70
  3   8  -96  -57  -47  -45  -29  -13   -2    0    3
  4   2  -74  -18    0
  5   1    0    8
  6   1  589    0
  7   3  -61  -44  -26    0
  8   1  -55    0
  9   5  -18    0    9   18   50   58
 10   7  -66  -36    0    2   16   46   62   82
 11   1    0    8
 12   8 -279 -272 -253 -229 -165 -121  -74  -38    0
 13   3  -24  -19  -17    0
 14   4  -43  -27  -21   -9    0
 15   5 -406  -91  -64  -29   -3    0
```

The column “Lst” gives the last entry in each row.

For the first version of the macro, I output diagnostic information for the first 200 sums to Sheet2:

[image: First 200 sums]

This was sufficient for me to believe the macro was cycling the speedometer correctly, extracting values from the matrix correctly and summing those values correctly.

For the second version of the macro, I removed all diagnostic code and output the sums to a file.  I switch files after 1,000,000 sums to keep the file sizes manageable.  After creating file 50, the macro exited.  Creating those 50 files took 13 minutes 15 seconds.  The top of the first file is:

[image: File 0001]

I then switched to Visual Basic 2010.  I created a Windows Application with a simple form:

[image: Form]

I have six controls of which four are named as shown and another `lblMessage` is not visible until the end.  The value 8000 for `lblFileNumMax` is replaced at runtime by the calculated number of files to be created.  The value 1 for `lblFileNumCrnt` is updated every time a new file is created.  With about 100 created per minute, this provides an adequate indication of progress.

I could have loaded the matrix from Excel but I decided it was easier to hard code.  Apart from that there is little difference in the code from the VBA version.  I retained the trap that stopped the generation after 50 files had been created and used a batch file to check the VBA files were the same as the VB files:

```
Del compare.txt
comp "Sums 0001.txt" "Sums 00001VBA.txt" <N.txt >>Compare.txt
comp "Sums 0002.txt" "Sums 00002VBA.txt" <N.txt >>Compare.txt
comp "Sums 0003.txt" "Sums 00003VBA.txt" <N.txt >>Compare.txt
comp "Sums 0004.txt" "Sums 00004VBA.txt" <N.txt >>Compare.txt
comp "Sums 0005.txt" "Sums 00005VBA.txt" <N.txt >>Compare.txt
```

I then removed the trap and let the program create all 8063 files which took 51 minutes 45 seconds on my 2.1 GHz laptop.

I cannot post the VBA code because I accidentally deleted it along with the 8063 files totally 40 Gb which were big enough to cause my recycle bin to overflow.

The VB.net code is below.

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
  Dim fileOut As StreamWriter
  Private Sub cmdStart_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdStart.Click

    Dim matrix(,) As Integer = {{-144, -5, 0, 12, 16, 20, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                {-16, 0, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                {0, 5, 8, 11, 70, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                {-96, -57, -47, -45, -29, -13, -2, 0, 3}, _
                                {-74, -18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                {0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                {589, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                {-61, -44, -26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                {-55, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                {-18, 0, 9, 18, 50, 58, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                {-66, -36, 0, 2, 16, 46, 62, 82, 0}, _
                                {0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                {-279, -272, -253, -229, -165, -121, -74, -38, 0}, _
                                {-24, -19, -17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                {-43, -27, -21, -9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, _
                                {-406, -91, -64, -29, -3, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

    Dim lastEntryPerRow() As Integer = {5, 2, 4, 8, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 7, 1, 8, 3, 4, 5}

    Const sumsPerFile As Long = 1000000

    Dim fileOutNum As Integer
    Dim fileOutNumMax As Long
    Dim finished As Boolean
    Dim numSums As Integer
    Dim pathProg As String
    Dim posChar As Int32
    Dim speedo() As Integer
    Dim sumCrnt As Integer
    Dim rowCrnt As Integer
    Dim rowMax As Integer = matrix.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim timeStart As Long

    cmdStart.Visible = False
    cmdExit.Visible = False

    ' Extract folder containing program
    pathProg = Application.ExecutablePath
    posChar = InStrRev(pathProg, "\")
    If posChar <> 0 Then
      ' Discard the name of the program
      pathProg = Mid(pathProg, 1, posChar)
    End If

    ' Initialise Speedo to all zeros
    ReDim speedo(rowMax)
    For rowCrnt = 0 To rowMax
      speedo(rowCrnt) = 0
    Next

    ' Calculate number of files to be created
    fileOutNumMax = 1
    For rowCrnt = 0 To rowMax
      fileOutNumMax *= CLng(lastEntryPerRow(rowCrnt) + 1)
    Next
    fileOutNumMax = CInt(fileOutNumMax / sumsPerFile)

    lblFileNumMax.Text = CStr(fileOutNumMax)

    ' Initialise control variables
    numSums = 0
    fileOutNum = 1
    finished = False
    lblFileNumCrnt.Text = CStr(fileOutNum)
    Application.DoEvents()

    timeStart = (Hour(DateTime.Now) * 24 + Minute(DateTime.Now)) * 60 + Second(DateTime.Now)

    Do While True

      ' False means overwrite if file already exists
      fileOut = New StreamWriter(pathProg & "\Sums " & Format(fileOutNum, "0000") & ".txt", False)

      Do While True

        ' Output sum identified by current value of Speedo
        sumCrnt = 0
        numSums = numSums + 1
        For rowCrnt = 0 To rowMax
          sumCrnt += matrix(rowCrnt, speedo(rowCrnt))
        Next
        fileOut.WriteLine(sumCrnt)

        ' Generate next value for Speedo
        ' Process entries from left to right
        For rowCrnt = 0 To rowMax
          If speedo(rowCrnt) = lastEntryPerRow(rowCrnt) Then
            ' This column is about to overflow
            speedo(rowCrnt) = 0
            If rowCrnt = rowMax Then
              ' rightmost entry has overflowed. All done
              finished = True
              Exit Do
            End If
            ' Continue with For-Loop to step next column to right
          Else
            ' This column is not about to overflow
            speedo(rowCrnt) = speedo(rowCrnt) + 1
            ' Have finished generation
            Exit For
          End If
        Next

        If numSums >= sumsPerFile Then
          Exit Do
        End If

      Loop

      fileOut.Close()
      fileOut = Nothing
      numSums = 0
      fileOutNum = fileOutNum + 1
      'If fileOutNum >= 51 Then
      '  Exit Do
      'End If
      If finished Then
        Exit Do
      End If
      lblFileNumCrnt.Text = CStr(fileOutNum)
      Application.DoEvents()

    Loop

    Debug.Print(CStr((Hour(DateTime.Now) * 24 + Minute(DateTime.Now)) * 60 + _
                      Second(DateTime.Now) - timeStart) & " seconds")

    cmdExit.Visible = True

  End Sub
  Private Sub cmdExit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdExit.Click

    If fileOut IsNot Nothing Then
      fileOut.Close()
      fileOut = Nothing
    End If

    Me.Close()

  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer feels right. I understand the theory of it, but I'm not familiar with implementing arrays as parameters for loops. Could you point me to the right direction?

Comment: Would I need to have a loop layer for each row and then fill up the array?

Comment: I am testing the outer loop at the moment.  What I had not thought about was how many values you are going to generate.  16^56 values are going to take a long time to generate and need a lot of storage space.

Comment: Thanks, @Tony Dallimore. I found out just 15-20 minutes ago that I can de-Dup on the 0s. That being said, I have to evaluate only one 0 per row, so I'm able to compress my data down to a 16row x 9col matrix. Much better.

Comment: 16^9 is better than 16^56 but it will still take a looooong time.  My rough calculation suggests it will take days.

Comment: Ouch. Is there a way to segment the work load?... maybe Excel isn't the solution here then. I may have to look into going the SQL Server route. Thanks for the effort though. Good insight.

Comment: To generate all values for columns 11 to 15 took 2 seconds. To generate all values for columns 10 to 15 took 13 seconds. To generate all values for columns 9 to 15 took 116 seconds. To generate all values for columns 8 to 15 took 1,047 seconds. Each extra column takes about 9 times longer than the previous. This is will take years.

Comment: I will post the code if you wish but I am not sure of its value.

Comment: Thanks again for the help and advice. No need for the code since, as you said, it wouldn't be practical. I'm marking your answer as correct though, since it's a good and true one technically.